# Facing a type mismatch error while sending the message to the SQS queue

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-sqs

Facing an error with the SQS queue implementation. I am following the below docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_sqs_code_examples.html, but I am facing a type mismatch error while sending the message to the queue. I am attaching package information and an error snapshot for reference.
`Package:@aws-sdk/client-sqs`
`package version: ^3.379.1`

```
import {SendMessageCommand} from '@aws-sdk/client-sqs';
import {AnyObject} from '@loopback/repository';
import {getSQSclient} from './sqs-client';


const MAX_RETRIES = 3;
let currentAttempt = 1;
export async function publishToSQS(imageInfo: AnyObject) {
  try {
    // Create an SQS client using the getSQSclient function
    const sqs = await getSQSclient();
    // Send message to SQS queue using the SQS client
    const command = new SendMessageCommand({
      QueueUrl: process.env.SQS_URL,
      MessageBody: JSON.stringify(imageInfo),
    });

    // Execute the command and capture the result

    const result = await sqs.send(command);

    log.info('Message sent successfully to SQS:', result);
  } catch (err) {
    log.error(`Error sending message to SQS (Attempt ${currentAttempt}/${MAX_RETRIES}):`, err);
    if (currentAttempt < MAX_RETRIES) {
      currentAttempt++;
      await publishToSQS(imageInfo);
    } else {
      // Log an error if maximum retries reached without success
      log.error('All retry attempts failed. Message not sent.', {failedImageInfo: imageInfo});
    }
  }
```

I wanted to send the message to the `SQS queue`, but its giving me an error. I'm not able to send the message.

```
    error TS2345: Argument of type 'SendMessageCommand' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Command<ServiceInputTypes, SendMessageCommandInput, ServiceOutputTypes, SendMessageCommandOutput, SmithyResolvedConfiguration<...>>'. Types of property 'resolveMiddleware' are incompatible. Type '(clientStack: MiddlewareStack<ServiceInputTypes, ServiceOutputTypes>, configuration: SQSClientResolvedConfig, options?: HttpHandlerOptions | undefined) => Handler<...>' is not assignable to type '(stack: MiddlewareStack<ServiceInputTypes, ServiceOutputTypes>, configuration: SmithyResolvedConfiguration<HttpHandlerOptions>, options: any) => Handler<...>'.
```

the `error` also consist
 `Property 'identifyOnResolve' is missing in type 'import("/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/node_modules/@smithy/types/dist-types/middleware").MiddlewareStack<import("/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sqs/dist-types/SQSClient").ServiceInputTypes, import("/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sqs/dist-types/SQSClient").ServiceOutputTypes>' but required in type 'import("/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sqs/node_modules/@smithy/types/dist-types/middleware").MiddlewareStack<import("/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sqs/dist-types/SQSClient").ServiceInputTypes, import("/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sqs/dist-types/SQSClient").ServiceOutputTypes>` its failing at the package itself

Comment: Please Edit your Question and show us your code and the _exact_ error message. (Please attach as text, not images.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the mismatch for the function is but it seems that there is one. For comparison, you may find use in [this example from the example code library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/sqs_example_sqs_SendMessage_section.html). Note that if you have a FIFO queue, some additional properties are required. You shouldn't need attributes or delay, but they are included in the example.

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create an SQS service object
var sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});

var params = {
   // Remove DelaySeconds parameter and value for FIFO queues
  DelaySeconds: 10,
  MessageAttributes: {
    "Title": {
      DataType: "String",
      StringValue: "The Whistler"
    },
    "Author": {
      DataType: "String",
      StringValue: "John Grisham"
    },
    "WeeksOn": {
      DataType: "Number",
      StringValue: "6"
    }
  },
  MessageBody: "Information about current NY Times fiction bestseller for week of 12/11/2016.",
  // MessageDeduplicationId: "TheWhistler",  // Required for FIFO queues
  // MessageGroupId: "Group1",  // Required for FIFO queues
  QueueUrl: "YOUR_SQS_QUEUE_URL"
};

sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data.MessageId);
  }
});
```

You can [clone this repository](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javascript/example_code/sqs#code-examples) and run the examples for yourself also, which can be useful when tracking down a mismatch.

Comment: I tried it, but it failed while running It was breaking at the module @aws-sdk/client-sqsn itself

Comment: i have added the error below with which its failing